# Crash reports for OS X apps

Tags: xcode, macos, crash-reports

How does one obtain crash reports uploaded to Apple for OS X apps?  A user reported a crash with one of my OS X apps, and said he shared the report with Apple.  Using XCode 8, I do not see any crash reports for that version or any version of my macOS app.  I do see crash reports for an iOS app in XCode.

In iTunes connect, if I navigate to the current version of the OS X app, under the "App Store" tab there is a link for "Crash Reports" at the bottom of the page, but clicking this navigates to a generic FAQ for crash reports, and this has a link which explains how to view crash report in XCode for iOS apps.

I have searched the web for an answer, without success. Is it not possible to get macOS app crash reports?

Answer (score 1):

I may have found my answer in Apple Technical Note TN2123: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2004/tn2123.html

> CrashReporter currently has a number of limitations.
>
> There is currently no way for third party developers to access the reports submitted via CrashReporter. Apple is aware that there is strong demand for such a facility (r. 3356232). In fact, various third party developers have implemented their own crash reporting mechanisms: these range from the simple (have the application look at its own crash log file at launch time; if it has changed, offer to submit it to the developer) to the exceeding complex (completely reimplement CrashReporter).

This was last updated in 2008.