# How to view crash reports in Xcode

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I've seen several (e.g. [question1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39670073/crash-reports-for-os-x-apps), [question2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64807106/crash-reports-show-up-in-app-store-connect-but-not-in-xcode-organizer), [question3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43679548/testflight-crash-log-not-showing-in-xcode)) questions about viewing crash reports that don't help me.  Since I'm new to Apple development, my questions sort of translates to "is this how I'm supposed to open crash reports?"

Here's what I'm doing:

1. Open project in Xcode (version 12.4)
2. Navigate to Window->Organizer and click "Crashes"
3. Select the release build (1.2) for which I'm trying to view crash reports

Because Xcode shows no crash reports for that particular release (I do see some for older releases), I did this:

1. Login to App Store Connect
2. Navigate to App Analytics->MyApp->Crashes
3. Click "Add Filter" then App Version -> 1.2

This page shows that there have been over 100 crashes for this build in the last month (and they pretty well span the whole month).  I am expecting to be able to view a report for each one of these.  Is that not necessarily possible?

In response to some of the SO questions I've seen, I've done this:

1. Navigate to TestFlight->Build 1.2-> Build Metadata to verify I have included Symbols
2. Navigate to Users and Access->MyAccount to verify I have admin permission and Access to Reports
3. Restarted Xcode

What else should I be doing?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Window menu, choose "Devices and Simulators". Plug in an iPhone or iPad. *Even if the logs are for Mac apps*.

Click on the device you plugged in in the left column. To the right find the button "View Device Logs".

In the new window click on "All Logs". You can drag any .ips fils onto the left window to view them. You can right click on any file to symbolicate them.

All this makes me think that someone at Apple has lost their mind.

In my case the symbolicate doesn't work and the logs don't display correctly

Comment: When I try to import a crash log (.ips extension) from App store Review (where app crashes but other users with modern hardware do not experience this), all I see after importing is the first part of the log. The display stops at Crashed Thread. Re-symbolicate Log does nothing.